# inet addr missing after ifconfig

Tags: server, ifconfig, owncloud-server, ip-address

I am making a cloud server and am following [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s3pryWdZyas). Everything went FUBAR when I used the `ifconfig` command in the terminal and did not receive the IP of my server. I have also tried `ifconfig -a` with no success. I require the IP address to move on to the next step.

I typed exactly, `ifconfig`:

[image: screen capture]

Comment: Please give as exactly witch command you type.

Comment: There is IPv6 (inet6) address assigned to the interface eth0, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. I have no idea what I am doing. Im afraid Im a chemist not a code monkey

Comment: Assigning an ip address to a NIC does not require one to be a _code monkey_. Have a look over at https://www.swiftstack.com/docs/install/configure_networking.html.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the inetaddr is missing could be that you're not connected to the internet.

As was in my case, if your Linux is hosted in a VM, ensure you have enabled networking.

[image]